# C++ select stops accepting connections

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, select

I'm trying to make a select-server in order to receive connection from several clients (all clients will connect to the same port).
The server accepts the first 2 clients, but unless one of them disconnects, it will not accept a new one.
I'm starting to listen the the server port like this:

```
listen(m_socketId, SOMAXCONN);
```

and using the select command like this:

```
int selected = select(m_maxSocketId + 1, &m_socketReadSet, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

I've added some code.

```
bool TcpServer::Start(char* ipAddress, int port)
{
    m_active = true;
    FD_ZERO(&m_socketMasterSet);
    bool listening = m_socket->Listen(ipAddress, port);
    // Start listening.

    m_maxSocketId = m_socket->GetId();
    FD_SET(m_maxSocketId, &m_socketMasterSet);
    if (listening == true)
    {
        StartThread(&InvokeListening);
        StartReceiving();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void TcpServer::Listen()
{
    while (m_active == true)
    {
        m_socketReadSet = m_socketMasterSet;
        int selected = select(m_maxSocketId + 1, &m_socketReadSet, NULL, NULL, 0);
        if (selected <= 0)
            continue;
        bool accepted = Accept();
        if (accepted == false)
        {
            ReceiveFromSockets();
        }
    }
}

bool TcpServer::Accept()
{
    int listenerId = m_socket->GetId();
    if (FD_ISSET(listenerId, &m_socketReadSet) == true)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in remoteAddr;
        int addrSize = sizeof(remoteAddr);
        unsigned int newSockId = accept(listenerId, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteAddr, &addrSize);
        if (newSockId == -1) // Invalid socket...
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (newSockId > m_maxSocketId)
        {
            m_maxSocketId = newSockId;
        }

        m_clientUniqueId++;
        // Remembering the new socket, so we'll be able to check its state
        // the next time.
        FD_SET(newSockId, &m_socketMasterSet);

        CommEndPoint remote(remoteAddr);
        CommEndPoint local = m_socket->GetLocalPoint();

        ClientId* client = new ClientId(m_clientUniqueId, newSockId, local, remote);
        m_clients.Add(client);
        StoreNewlyAcceptedClient(client);
        char acceptedMsg = CommInternalServerMsg::ConnectionAccepted;
        Server::Send(CommMessageType::Internal, client, &acceptedMsg, sizeof(acceptedMsg));
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I hope it's enough :)
what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not allowed to copy construct fd_set objects:

```
 m_socketReadSet = m_socketMasterSet;
```

This combined with Nikolai's correct statement that `select` changes the set passed in probably accounts for your error.

`poll` (On Windows, [WSAPoll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741669.aspx)) is a much friendlier API.

Windows also provides `WSAEventSelect` and `(Msg)WaitForMultipleObjects(Ex)`, which doesn't have a direct equivalent on Unix, but allows you to wait on sockets, files, thread synchronization events, timers, and UI messages at the same time.

Comment: ok, so how can I update the FD_SET? I'd prefer to use "select" in order to be compatible with unix as well. :)

Comment: @ldov: Sometimes there's an `FD_COPY` macro, but I don't think VC++ provides it.  You'd need to keep an array of the socket handles, and loop through calling `FD_SET` for each one.  At which point you're better off with `poll`, and a tiny amount of OS-specific code.  Despite different names, `WSAPoll` and `poll` work exactly the same way, right down to the order of parameters.  Windows `select` unfortunately isn't 100% compatible with BSD sockets anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The by far most common error with `select()` is not re-initializing the fd sets on every iteration. The second, third, and forth arguments are *updated* by the call, so you have to populate them again *every time*.

Post more code, so people can actually help you.

#### Edit 0:

[`fd_set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows is a mess :)